# Inheriting behaviours for set and frozenset seem to differ

Tags: python, inheritance, immutability, built-in-types

Can someone explain the following behaviour:

```
class derivedset1(frozenset):
    def __new__(cls,*args):
        return frozenset.__new__(cls,args)  

class derivedset2(set):
    def __new__(cls,*args):
        return set.__new__(cls,args)    

a=derivedset1('item1','item2') # WORKS 
b=derivedset2('item1','item2') # DOESN'T WORK

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inheriting-behaviours.py", line 12, in <module>
    b=derivedset2('item1','item2') # DOESN'T WORK
TypeError: derivedset2 expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

This is surprising to me that you can alter the constructor of a frozen set whereas it is not possible for the constructor of a mutable set.

Comment: Interesting data point: `b=derivedset2(['item1','item2'])` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__`() method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where `self` is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to `__new__()`.

`set.__init__` only takes one argument, an iterable specifying the initial set contents. Therefore, you should add your own initializer which takes all additional arguments and supplies them as the initial set values:

```
class derivedset2(set):
    def __new__(cls,*args):
        return set.__new__(cls,*args)

    def __init__(self, *initial_values):
        set.__init__(self, initial_values)
```

Notice that you should overwrite `__init__` and refrain from implementing `__new__` unless you want to implement object caching, singletons, or similar weird stuff. Your subclassing works for `frozenset` precisely because `frozenset` **does** profit from object caching, i.e. the Python interpreter only needs one `frozenset` instance for two `frozenset` objects with the same content.

In general, you should refrain from sub-classing built-in classes, especially if your semantics are incompatible (in this case, `set([])` and `derivedset2([])` return totally different results).

Comment: The reason `frozenset` uses `__new__` isn't caching, but because it is immutable. If the elements were consumed by `__init__`, the class would have to be somewhat-mutable. Then `fs = frozenset.__new__(frozenset)` would create an empty `frozenset` that could be filled (mutated) with `fs.__init__([1, 2, 3])`. This would happen each time during subclassing.

Comment: The value for immutable objects has to be established at the point of creation -- in the `__new__()` method -- precisely because it can't be done later in the `__init__()` method.